# Why use "modestly" to describe Moller in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have copied this excerpt from a [NPR news transcript](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=300616048) below

> ALSOP: Isn't it nice? It's very pleasant and sunny and sounds like
>   spring time. And, you know, it really belies the enormity of this
>   piece and what's about to happen and the fact that Moller even gave it
>   the subtitle - he only used it for the first two performances - but
>   the Titan, **modestly**, as he always did, of course.

Is Titan, Moller here?
And do the last few sentences means something like: "Though this is a masterpiece which he should be proud of, he is still humble"?

Comment: *Some modern performances and recordings give the work ([Symphony No. 1 in D major by Gustav Mahler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._1_(Mahler))) the title **Titan**, despite the fact that Mahler only used this label for two early performances.* I assume **Moller** is some kind of weird misspelling of **Mahler**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's not that weird a misspelling … they'd be pronounced the same in American English. I'd guess this dialogue was turned into text by a computer, and then corrected by an editor who didn't catch all the mistakes.

Comment: @Peter: It seems pretty weird to me that such a radically different spelling should occur *once* in a transcript containing *twenty-three* instances spelt correctly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why there is a "but" before the Titan, and  I still can't understand why the sentences prompt to " modestly, as he always did", which seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: Mooseorgie always titled his works modestly.

Comment: @CYC: Much of what these two guys are saying is pretty meaningless. Earlier, the interviewer said *"I believe in the same cookie"* (referring to *Oreos*, which were apparently "invented" in the same decade as the musical piece being discussed). Mostly it's just two guys billing and cooing.

Comment: The *but* is a discourse marker, indicating the speaker is returning to the topic he digressed from. And *modestly* is meant ironically.

Comment: IMHO the use of "enormity" in what I'll describe generously as a "new modern meaning" ("large size", rather than the traditional "really bad") is generally a marker of someone who's trying to sound much more erudite than they really are. So I wouldn't worry too much about yourself if you missed the meaning of things a bit in that statement. The author did too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This particular conversation does not read well in the transcript due to the speakers using *extremely* informal language.

The speaker is using "modestly" sarcastically and the gist of the meaning is that Moller [sic] once subtitled [Symphony No. 1 in D major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._1_%28Mahler%29) "Titan" which, characteristically, is not very modest.

The "but" (as StoneyB notes in the comments) "is a discourse marker, indicating the speaker is returning to the topic he digressed from."